# How to make some image fit with the bootstrap columns with auto zoom image to fill the column

Tags: html, css, image, bootstrap-5

[image: The image fit and fill the column with zoom]

[image: This is the picture when open in mobile, and I want to be like this]

[image: This is the result when I try to fit 100%]

And this is my code :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
          <div class="xon-card">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://www.adidas.co.id/media/scandiweb/slider/9/6/960x500_3_.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://www.adidas.co.id/media/scandiweb/slider/m/e/mermaid--teaser-update-5.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

After that I want to make some button like that

I'm using bootstrap 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add style to img:

```
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
object-fit: cover;
```

Comment: Thanks i did it :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can handle it by `flex-wrap`. See the link below.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#wrap